# "Only one of the following can be installed at once" while installing ADT-23-0-2

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am having this issue while installing latest version of ADT

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

```
Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.java 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.104.0.v20121024-145224 (org.eclipse.ui 3.104.0.v20121024-145224)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
```